# Can I redirect an website without the SSL Certificate to one with a certificate?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, haproxy

Let's suppose that I have the following websites:

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
example.com

But only the website without 'www' is covered with an SSL Certificate, which means that whenever I try to connect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in modern browsers I can't.

If possible, I'd like to whenever someone connects to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), it gets redirected to example.com

I've tried every single possibilty, tweeking around with the configurations on haproxy, using SNI (Server Name Indication), but nothing seems to work out.

I just need a proper answer so that I can give up on this and finally get a certificate for my 'www' domain.